# Grails plugin databasemigration add domain object with hashmap

Tags: grails, hibernate-mapping, grails-plugin

I want to add this domain object to my application:

```
class DatatableListviewAvlColumns {

static constraints = {
}

static hasMany = [availableListviewColumns:  ListviewColumnDefinition]


static mapping = {
    availableListviewColumns cascade: 'all-delete-orphan'
}


Map<String, ListviewColumnDefinition> availableListviewColumns = new HashMap<>()

String datatableName
}
```

In my changelog.groovy, I added this:

```
 changeSet(author: "pm", id: "datatable_listview_avl_columns") {
    createTable(tableName: "datatable_listview_avl_columns") {
        column(name: "id", type: "BIGINT") {
            constraints(nullable: "false")
        }

        column(name: "version", type: "BIGINT") {
            constraints(nullable: "false")
        }

        column(name: "datatable_name", type: "TEXT") {
            constraints(nullable: "false")
        }
    }
}

changeSet(author: "pm", id: "datatable_listview_avl_columns_definition") {
    createTable(tableName: "datatable_listview_avl_columns_available_listview_columns") {
        column(name: "datatable_listview_avl_columns_id", type: "BIGINT") {
            constraints(nullable: "false")
        }
        column(name: "listview_column_definition_id", type: "BIGINT")

        column(name: "available_listview_columns_idx", type: "STRING")
    }
}
```

When I start the application, I get this exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'methodValidationPostProcessor' defined in class path resource ...... is org.hibernate.MappingException: Missing type or column for column[available_listview_columns_listview_column_definition] on domain[lomnido.DatatableListviewAvlColumns] referencing[com.lomnido.view.ListviewColumnDefinition]
```

What is the correct entry in the changelog.groovy for this situation?
I have never used a Hashmap with an object before, but I thing this should be possible? Or am I wrong?

Comment: You should use either hasMany or field, try to remove hasMany and try again

Comment: I removed the hasMany, but did not work. What is the correct entry in changelog.groovy for liquibase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake.
The ListViewColumndDefinition was not a domain object. So this could not work.